# HTML/Web Documentation in Intellisense & Tooltips in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tooltip

Are there any plug-ins or methods to add intellisense tooltips to Visual Studios web editor?

For example, viewing an .aspx webform, mousing over a  tag would pop-up a tool-tip with documentation info about the tag, like mousing over 'int' in

```
int integ = 2;
```

in the code editor will pop up with basic "Represents a 32-bit signed integer." tool-tip.

Similarly for javascript (where applicable), jQuery etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these helpful tools 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6 
http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.vsdoc 
http://blog.credera.com/topic/technology-solutions/microsoft-solutions/new-visual-studio-2012-features-for-javascript-developers/

may be this is useful to you.